# Fee level missing for booked participants using price-set

Tags: civievent, price-sets

For our annual conference I have created a price set for the tickets. These have been working ok but now I am looking at reports I've noticed that the tickets are all grouped to the booker's profile and the 'fee level' and amount to the other booked participants is blank and at 0. This means that I do not actually know who is booked onto which day.

For example - see below screen shot:

Anne Marie Nicholson has made a booking for her and three of her colleagues. 3 are for our one day conference and 1 for our Day 2 conference but everything is grouped to Anne Marie's profile with no info (other than the event name) as to which the other 3 colleagues are attending.

Is there a way around this in price-sets? I have looked at the editing options but can't see anything.

Thanks, Katie

[image]

Comment: http://www.gingerfeet.net/civicrm-userguide-price-sets this link provides a better way of using price sets.

Comment: hey and welcome to civi stackexchange - more information is better than less as it saves time for folks who are voluntarily helping so for example, it would have been helpful to reference the Report id you are using